# Exterior wall framing - Safe to remove 2x4 that was part of soffit/bulkhead?

Tags: framing, structural, soffit

I've removed all the soffits in my kitchen, however, there is one 2x4 that I have left until I could consult someone more knowledgeable.  I'm thinking the 2x4 was there just to hang the drywall underneath, however, it seems to run along the bottom of 2x10's that make up my exterior wall (sill?) that supports the floor joists of my 2nd floor. The house is a 2-story, brick home built in 1940.

I'm thinking the 2x4's that run up the wall should be toenailed into a single 2x4 that runs the bottom of those 2x10's but I can't see without taking out some more drywall.  Is it possible that this stud is structural in any way?  Thanks.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The 2x4 looks to be the the nailer ,to the soffit drywall. You should be able to remove it. Looking at the rest of your frame, i see a leak or a old leak.  You should look into that a bit.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I noticed only the one 2x10 was discolored.  There's no plumbing or anything above it except the vent for my kitchen sink which runs through that exterior wall. I'll take a look, thanks.

Comment: Even this posting looks like you could improve your work with an edit.

Comment: I don't follow @MichaelKaras, is there something in the photo you think I should improve?

Comment: @DrTarr - My comment was aimed at RobertMoody who I am hoping can do more work to improve his postings.