# How to retrofit existing kitchen exhaust fan

Tags: hvac, kitchens, exhaust-fan, exhaust-vent

I'm remodeling a kitchen that is circa 1940's.  In the kitchen is an exhaust fan that sits inside a 3.25x10 duct.  I would like to keep an exhaust fan in this location and re-use the existing duct, however, the fan motor is froze.  I'm trying to now understand what my best options are.

The fan motor plugs into an 110VAC receptacle (no ground) and is countersunk into a sort of frame that is inside the duct.  3 bolts hold the fan on, and they are on an 8" spacing.  I am guessing this is probably not a current standard.  I was hoping to avoid cutting out all the ceiling drywall and the duct, but it's staring to look that way.  Do you think there's any possibility of me re-purposing the in-ceiling hardware?

[image: Fan in ceiling]
[image: Fan removed 1]
[image: Fan removed 2]
[image: Fan bottom]
[image: Fan top]

---

Googling 10x3.25 exhaust fan, I found some like [this one here](https://www.zoro.com/broan-fan-assembly-part-97015157-includes-motor-blower-wheel-mounting-plate-97015157/i/G5178871/feature-product?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIwa2bw4iZ4wIVGbbICh1C9QunEAkYASABEgI1rvD_BwE), however, it's not clear if that's meant to go into a 10x3.25 duct or is a replacement part for some sort of larger assembly.  Does anyone have any experience with these Broan ceiling fans?

---

Possible replacements that use the 10x3.25" duct:
[Broan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00155YJCO).
[NuTone](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001POBPQ8)

Comment: This seems like a near-duplicate of the question you asked about a week ago: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/167952/how-to-re-purpose-an-exhaust-fan-using-a-10x3-25-duct

Comment: @dwizum, It looks like they got an answer for the vent portion of the question, but no one addressed the fan replacement.  Spoiler alert - you're not going to find a direct replacement for that fan motor.

Comment: You are right, I did ask the question earlier but I think I created some confusion when asking about the outdoor vent in the same question and never really got an answer.  Also, I am not optimistic about the direct replacement, but it would be good if I could at least find something that uses the 10x3.25 duct.

Answer (score 1):

That whole fan assembly will need to be replaced unless you want to do some work hand-making a bracket that will accept a modern exhaust fan motor.  Even then, the fan motors and blades for a modern install probably wouldn't move air efficiently in that size of enclosure.

Your main concern will be finding a new fan that is easy to connect to your 3x10 vent.  They are probably available, but most ceiling exhaust fans that I have seen are made for a round rigid or flex duct.